# How to write a hamiltonian in minimal basis as a spherical tensor

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, angular-momentum, tensor-calculus, spherical-harmonics

I am reading [this paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41524-022-00843-2) where the authors write the atom-blocks of the hamiltonian in a minimal basis set and use some regression technique to fit the hamiltonian to data. This question is about how to write an atom block of the hamiltonian as a spherical tensor if it is cartesian.

The authors of the paper write that their code assumes that a block in the hamiltonian transforms like this
$$
H_{IJ}(QR) = D(Q) H_{IJ}(R) D(Q)^*, \qquad D(Q) = \mathrm{diag}(D^1, D^2,\cdots). \qquad(1)
$$
For example, for the pp-block, my Hamiltonian blocks transfer as the Cartesian tensor:
$$
H_{p_ip_j}(QR) = Q H_{p_ip_j}(R) Q^*,
$$
and as I want to play along at home, I have decided to try to change the basis. [This video](https://youtu.be/1XkZSl-1Mrc) told me that there exists some equations that I can use to write a rank-2 tensor, $T_q^{(k)}$ in spherical basis. I assume the maker of the video means to say that a rank-2 tensor is a matrix of the form that I am interested in. The maker of the video say that if $T_{ij}$ are the cartesian elements, I can get the spherical tensor by:
$$
T_0^{(0)} = - \frac{1}{3^{1/2}} \Big[ T_{xx} +T_{yy} +T_{zz} \Big] \\
T_{\pm 1}^{(1)} = \frac{1}{2} \Big[ T_{zx}  - T_{xz}  \pm i ( T_{zy} - T_{yz}  ) \Big] \\
T_0^{(1)} = \frac{i}{2^{1/2}} \Big[ T_{xy}  - T_{yx}  \Big] \\
T_{\pm 2}^{(2)} = \frac{1}{2} \Big[ T_{xx}  - T_{yy}  \pm i ( T_{xy}  + T_{yx}  ) \Big] \\
T_{\pm 1}^{(2)} = \frac{1}{2} \Big[ \mp (T_{xz}  + T_{zx} ) - i (T_{yz}  + T_{zy} ) \Big] \\
T_0^{(2)} = - \frac{1}{6^{1/2}} \Big[ T_{xx}  + T_{yy}  - 2 T_{zz}  \Big] \\
$$
**Question:** What are the things that separate me from writing a hamiltonian block in a minimal basis as a spherical tensor? (A) Does it appear that I have any misunderstandings above? And (B) you can count that the number of elements above are 9 in total. But how should they be arranged in a the 3x3-matrix such that they transform by matrix-matrix multiplication in the way of equation (1) above?